# Not able to customize ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm working on developing a simple todo list app with a custom ListView.  I want to be able to change the colors (such as white text rather then black on the text view) and perhaps add a checkbox for each item in the ListView.

When using a default list view I need to use the layout.xml id '@android:id/list', however, to customize the view, I am using the id '@+id/task_list'. When I do this I receive the error:

```
"your content must have a listview whose id attribute is 'android.r.id.list'"
```

What should I do? And insight will be appreciated.

Below is the code that I am using.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.todo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<TextView> listItems=new ArrayList<TextView>();

ArrayAdapter<TextView> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(this,
        R.layout.task_row_item,
        listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void addItems(View view) {
    EditText newItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textField);
    TextView listItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task_description);
    listItems.add(listItem);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    newItem.setText("");
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/black"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter a task..."
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addItems"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="addItems"
        android:text="Add" />

</LinearLayout>

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/task_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

task_row_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_description"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either stop using `ListActivity` or replace

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/task_list"
```

with

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Get familiar with: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: I'm trying to use a custom List view.

Comment: what is `custom list view`? but none the less, it does not really matter what it is. List view does NOT need ListActivity unless you use special features ListActivity offers. IF you do not use, then extend regular Activity instead. If you use these features, you need to change id of your list as I wrote in my answer and what linked docs describe. I personally never use ListActivity myself

Comment: When I use an Activity rather then a ListActivity, it does not let me use 'setListAdapter(adapter);'.  Are there any other alternatives in this case? How do I fix this problem? Also thanks for the help, I appreciate it.